# Regex with negation for extracting web link

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex-negation

I have a text fragment:

```
.....https://www.one.com/privacy/\............http://two.com/terms/'.............https://three.com/pricing/\..........https://four.com/widget/wg74ythx;.........http://five.com/pricing .........
```

My code for extracting web links:
`link = re.compile(r'https?://(\w.*?)(\\|;|\'|\s)')`

But I need to exclude from my results all links with the words "privacy" or "widget".
I`m stuck here, and I need the help of the community.

Comment: can you just check the results for those words? `if 'privacy' in url:...`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a compile object you could do something like

`s = mystring
urls = [url[0] for url in re.findall(r'https?://(\w.*?)(\\|;|\'|\s)',s) \
        if not re.search('privacy|widget',url[0])]`